# Sql serialize columns into one record for search

Tags: mysql, join, view

I would like to create a search feature which looks in multiple tables and columns and return the main idea. For example:
(This is a very simplified scenario, and the real tables have way more columns in which I would like to search)

```
table 'lead':
id | name | created 
1  | john | 1/1/2014
2  | jack | 2/1/2014

table 'notes':
id | lead_id | created  | note
1  | 1       | 1/1/2014 | lead added
2  | 1       | 1/2/2014 | some change occurred
3  | 2       | 2/1/2014 | lead added
4  | 2       | 2/2/2014 | some updates
```

I would like to provide for example the string "2014" which would return lead.id 1,2
Or look for "updates" which would return lead.id 2.

I can either run a join every time the search is performed, or somehow create a view which looks like this:

```
id | text
1  | john 1/1/2014 1/1/2014 lead added 1/2/2014 some change occurred
2  | jack 2/1/2014 2/1/2014 lead added 2/2/2014 some updates
```

This way, the search would be in one table and provide a fairly quick results, the "work" is updating the records per id every time tables 'notes' is updated.
I know a view is the best way to do this, but I am not clear on how to serialize a join result into one textual column. Of course it is fairly easy with php (or any back end script) but I was wondering if this can be done in a manner similar to when a view is constantly updated.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Sounds like a task for a search engine, rather than an RDBMS.  Have you considered something like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)?

Comment: The feature is search box for a massive users/leads pseudo CRM service. It is all one giant heap of php+mysql+jquery. I don't understand the search engine reference, but I will investigate Solr and sphinx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` functions, somethink like this:

```
SELECT n.lead_id, CONCAT(l.name, " ", l.created, " ",GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(n.`created`," ",n.`note`), " ")) as text
FROM notes n
JOIN lead l ON l.id = n.lead_id
GROUP BY n.`lead_id`
ORDER BY n.`created` DESC
```

Inner `CONCAT` forms submessage `1/1/2014 lead added`, `GROUP CONCAT` joins then and the outer `CONCAT` forms result message `john 1/1/2014 1/1/2014 lead added 1/2/2014 some change occurred`

Here is [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7950e/3)